# CSS word-wrapping?

Tags: html, css

This is usually a simple thing to do I thought but for some reason I just can't get it.

So as you can see below (snippet), I have a ul with lis that are fixed to the left side of the screen as small tabs. When hovered over, they expand. I am trying to make it so that it just reveals the straight line of text instead of un-wrapping it as it expands. What do I do?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#navTabs {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
#navTabs li {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  height: 75px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-left: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 100;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width .75s;
  list-style: none;
  word-wrap: none;
}
#navTabs li:hover {
  width: 250px;
}
#navTabs li h1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul id="navTabs">
    <li>
      <h1>HOME</h1>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
      <h1>NOT HOME</h1>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `white-space: nowrap` to prevent the text from wrapping to the next line.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#navTabs {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
#navTabs li {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  height: 75px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-left: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 100;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width .75s;
  list-style: none;
  word-wrap: none;

  /* added this: */
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#navTabs li:hover {
  width: 250px;
}
#navTabs li h1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul id="navTabs">
    <li>
      <h1>HOME</h1>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
      <h1>NOT HOME</h1>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using margin-left instead of width like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#navTabs {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
#navTabs li {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  height: 75px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-left: -230px;
  position: relative;
  top: 100;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .75s;
  list-style: none;
  word-wrap: none;

}
#navTabs li:hover {
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
#navTabs li h1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul id="navTabs">
    <li>
      <h1>HOME</h1>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
      <h1>NOT HOME</h1>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add something like this `<nobr>NOT HOME</nobr>`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#navTabs {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
#navTabs li {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  height: 75px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-left: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 100;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width .75s;
  list-style: none;
  word-wrap: none;
}
#navTabs li:hover {
  width: 250px;
}
#navTabs li h1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul id="navTabs">
    <li>
      <h1>HOME</h1>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
      <h1><nobr>NOT HOME</nobr></h1>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use markup to change the visual presentation.

Comment: @darthmaim I shouldn't have but this seemed helpful

Comment: Not good practise as [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nobr) suggests. It could be used in the context of paragraphs, but it's a non-standard tag so better not use it at all.

Comment: @Midas Better not use it

Answer (score 0):

Ashkay's answer if correct. Anyway you can also manipulate `margin-left` instead of `width`. Then you will achieve nice effect of moving text with the box.

See the snippet below.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#navTabs {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
#navTabs li {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  height: 75px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-left: -240px;
  position: relative;
  top: 100;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: margin .75s;
  list-style: none;
  word-wrap: none;
}
#navTabs li:hover {
  margin-left: 0;
}
#navTabs li h1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul id="navTabs">
    <li>
      <h1>HOME</h1>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
      <h1>NOT HOME</h1>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```